# Проверить есть input по атрибуту name. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

есть форма :

```
<form class="js-ajax-form"> <!-- Ivan Triumphov code Get8(amoCRM) убрал action="/forms/sendmail.php" method="post" -->
    <input type="hidden" name="reachgoal" value="mainRightForm" class="js-reach-goal">
    <input type="hidden"  name="type_form" value="zayvka">
    <input class="field" placeholder="Имя" name="fio">
    <input class="field" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" id="phone1">
</form>
```

как проверить есть поле у формы? по атрибуту `name`
так `$('.js-ajax-form').is('input[name="phone"]');` всегда false

Comment: потому что вместо `is` нужно использовать `has`

Comment: да точно... спасибо)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) проверяет соответствует ли текущая коллекция выбранных элементов, указанному селектору.

Так как выбрана форма, она не соответствует селектору `'input[name="phone"]'` и результат закономерно - false.

Вместо этого можно воспользоваться методами [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Все эти методы возвращают коллекцию, следовательно проверять надо будет количество оставшихся элементов.

Например

```
$('.js-ajax-form').has('input[name="phone"]').length > 0
```

В этом случае - поле присутствует, если равно 0 - отсутствует.

Comment: спасибо, думаю буду использовать этот код